# Subtracting 1 from integers in my list until zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of 5 numbers generated from as a random sample
I need to process each of the numbers in the list by subtracting 1 and then 1 and then 1 until it reached 0. I will need each of the numbers later for other processes.
For example: the number is 10, I will need to generate 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2 and 1.

`sample([i for i in range(50)], 5)`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2tsE.png)

*Heres the entire question if you're willing to try it out ill be super appreciative

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you would expect for a given input of 5 numbers?

Comment: So basically the question requires me to find the sum of numbers squared leading up to the random integer generated

For example:
The random list generated is [5, 6, 1, 9, 10]
The expected return would be 1^2 + 2^2 + ... +5^2 and then repeated for the other 4 values in the list, and then finally the sum of everything.

Comment: That doesn't seem to match with the question at all. The question sounds like you want to generate 5 numbers, which you're doing, and then do `range(x)` on each of those numbers.

Comment: My bad, I got mixed up with another question. The random list generated is [5, 6, 1, 9, 10] The expected return would be 4,3,2,1 for the first element, 5,4,3,2,1 for the second element, nothing for the third element, and 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 for the 4th element and so on....

Answer (score 0):

```py
def generate_lists(sampled_numbers):

  result = []

  for num in sampled_numbers:
    result.append([x for x in range(num, 0, -1)])

  return result
```

you could have another function to work with the results. Or use `yield` to iterate over the list if the elements or size `sampled_numbers` is too large

Answer (score 0):

to reverse loop specify third parameter in `range(n, 0, -1)`

```
numbers = [3,4,5]
numbers = [[i for i in range(n-1, 0, -1) if i > 0] for n in numbers]
print(numbers)
# [[2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```